# How to customize wordpress portfolio grid to replace attributes output with text of single portfolio?

Tags: php, wordpress, customization

I am a php newbie but have to resolve the following issue in some way:

In my …portfolio_grid.php I succeeded in understanding that this part:

```
$output .= '
            <a class="classic-portfolio-box normal-type-prt'.$colorize_fx_class.'" href="'.get_permalink($post_id).'" title="'.get_the_title().'"'.$colorize_hover.'></a>
            <div class="portfolio-box">
                <div class="portfolio-naming">
                    <h2 class="portfolio-title">'.get_the_title().'</h2>';
                if( !empty($on_attributes) ){
                    $output .= '
                    <h3 class="portfolio-attributes">'.$on_attributes.'</h3>';
                }
                $output .= '</div>
            </div>
            <img src="'.$image[0].'" width="'.$image[1].'" height="'.$image[2].'" alt="'.get_the_title().'" />
        ';
```

is responsible for what appears in my portfolio boxes. Now I’d like to change the following detail:

```
$output .= '
                    <h3 class="portfolio-attributes">'.$on_attributes.'</h3>';
```

Instead of the content of the $on_attributes variable I’d like to put out the content of the single portfolios texts field instead. I bet this is possible.

How can I fetch the content of the text field of each single portfolio post and put it out there? I know that somehow the the_content() or get_the_content() function will play a role but how is it to be done exactly? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: did you try $output .= ' <h3 class="portfolio-attributes">'. get_the_content(). '</h3>'; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already mentioned the answer in your question:

```
'<h3 class="portfolio-attributes">' . get_the_content() . '</h3>';
```

This assumes the the "text of a portfolio item" is actually saved as the WP `content` in your database.

As a side note, I'm not sure why you're concatenating everything as a string in this case...A wonderful thing about PHP is the ability to weave it in with standard HTML:

```
<h3 class="portfolio-attributes"><?php the_content(); ?></h3>
```

Comment: Awesomely simple! Wow! I thought it would be difficult to get the right portfolio id’s or else… I am beginning to like php.